# Updated version of Browser Security Handbook

Tags: web-application, web-browser

Google's [Browser Security Handbook](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Main) is a brilliant resource for web application security, and in particular, for understanding how browsers behave.  It discusses many issues, and contains tables showing behavior for a variety of browsers (MSIE6-8, FF2, FF3, Safari, Opera, Chrome, Android).  The latter are especially useful, because they concisely show the variety and diversity of security-relevant behavior among popular browsers.  If you are writing a web application, this helps you ensure that you have covered all likely behavior of all likely browsers.

However, the handbook hasn't been updated in a while.  Also, its tables don't list some of the most modern browsers (they haven't been updated to reflect the most modern versions of many browsers).

Is there an updated resource that provides information comparable to the Browser Security Handbook, but contains more up-to-date information?  Is there a place with a summary of behavior of browser behavior, across many browsers, for different kinds of security-relevant situations -- similar to the Browser Security Handbook has, but for more modern browsers?

Comment: Ask @lcamtuf on Twitter.

Comment: No need to write to Michal Zalewsky on Twitter, his homepage http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/ is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The Browser Security Handbook laid the foundation for his book: [The Tangled Web](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/tangled/) which (as of Nov 2012) is the most current book form the same author.  I purchased the book about a year ago and think it's a fantastic read.

As far as I know he hasn't released any newer or more updated information (appendix, etc) [outside of his blog.](http://lcamtuf.blogspot.com/) But [this entry as of 11/16](http://lcamtuf.blogspot.com/2012/11/lessons-in-history.html) says he is working on a new book, though I haven't seen specifics yet.